How to convert a jpeg packets in wireshark to a jpg image?
I have captured a traffic with content-type image/jpeg.
I have the tcp stream. How do I convert it to a jpg image file?
I have tried to save the tcp stream as a bin file and use an online site to convert it, but I get errors of invalid file.
Help is much appreciated!

If the stream is complete, then you should be able to utilize Wireshark's "Export Objects" feature to save the jpg image, e.g., "File -> Export Objects -> HTTP..."
